# Is there a way to test one jupyter notebook from another jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i am trying to **test one jupyter notebook from another**. Currently, I have my **first notebook, Testing1**, holding this function in one cell:

```
def add(a, b):
return a + b
```

and my **second notebook, Testing2,** with this test code in one cell:

```
import unittest


class TestNotebook(unittest.TestCase):


def test_add(self):
    self.assertEqual(add(2, 3), 5)
    self.assertEqual(add(4, 3), 7)
```

and this code in the cell below:

```
unittest.main(argv=[''], verbosity=2, exit=False)
```

Finally, **in a third notebook**, **Testing3**, i have this code, to my understanding compiles Testing1 and Testing2 and runs it:

```
%run Testing2.ipynb
```

Now, **all 3 notebooks are in the same folder**, and when i **save all 3** and run **Testing3**, **it works!** it executes the tests correctly.
My problem is when I change the code a bit in **Testing1**, say, to this:

```
def add(a, b):
x = (a + b) + 1 //Note the added 1
return x
```

and save it, then change my test in **Testing2** to accommodate the added 1:

```
import unittest


class TestNotebook(unittest.TestCase):

def test_add(self):
    self.assertEqual(add(2, 3), 6) //Note the added 1
    self.assertEqual(add(4, 3), 8) //Note the added 1
```

and save it then **run Testing2 and Testing3**, the old tests (before my edit to add one) run! for example; I will get output that

```
5 != 6
```

but i changed the function in Testing1 so that the output should be 6 and the test should pass. But, the test still runs the old version, before I edited and changed the function, **despite me saving it after!**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try adding `autoreload`: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Comment: In which notebook?

Comment: It's actually just a guess. I'd try putting it in all of them just to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately didnt work - For some reason changes in Testing1 are not being reflected in Testing2, this may have to do with the fact that I have no idea how the 2 are even linked with the code I have